# What is a good approach for an accounting algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, accounting

I need to create an accounting algorithm in PHP that computes the following.

I am developing an application for members contributing a fixed amount of money on daily basis. Let's say the daily contributing amount is $200, and members can prepay for given numbers of days.

For instance, if start date of contribution is 2015 April-1 and a member pays $600, the algorithm should distribute the amount from 2015 April-1 to 2015 April-3.

If he pays the next contribution on 2015 April-10 and pays $2000 the algorithm should first pay the deficit from date 2015 April-4 to 2015 April-10 amounting to $1400 then distribute the balance as from 2015 April-11 to 2015 April-13 amounting to $600.

I was trying with the following code, which attempts to add logic to detect when user have overpaid and if overpaid, the algorithm to distribute the amount evenly as described above. And if he had underpaid, the algorithm should add a row in the defaulter row, the last paid date should be picked as recently added row in the contributions tables.

```
public function actionBackdate() {
        $start = new DateTime("2015-03-1");
        $now=new DateTime();
        $now->modify('+1 day');
        $days = $now->diff($start);
        echo $now->format('Y-m-d g:i a');
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $days->format('%a')." have passed since";
        echo "<br/>";
        $contributionAmount=200;
        $TotalContributed=5400;
        $amountContributed=0;
        $oustandingBalance=0;

        $contributionDetails=array(
                                  "memberid"    =>4,
                                  "payment_mode"=>"CASH",
                                  "payment_for" =>"Chama Daily",
                                  "payment_ref" =>rand(9,9999),
                                  "amount"      =>"",
                                  "currency"    =>"KSH",
                                  "created_at"  =>"",
                                  "updated_at"  =>""
                                  );
        $defaulter=array(
                                  "memberid"    =>4,
                                  "currency"    =>"KSH",
                                  "amount_defaulted"=>"",
                                  "date_defaulted" =>"Daily Contrib",
                                  "fine_amount" =>50,
                                  "note"      =>"Contribution defaulter",
                                  "status"    =>0
                                  );

        for( $i=0;$i<(int)$days->format('%a')+1;$i++){

            //underpayment from expeted contribution amount
            if($TotalContributed<$contributionAmount && $TotalContributed>0 ){              
                echo "He had a balance of ".($contributionAmount-$TotalContributed)." at date ".$start->format('Y-m-d g:i a')."<br/>";
                $oustandingBalance+=($contributionAmount-$TotalContributed);
            }elseif($TotalContributed==0){
                // paid 0                 
                $oustandingBalance+=($contributionAmount-$TotalContributed);
                $defaulter['amount_defaulted']=$contributionAmount;
                $defaulter['date_defaulted']  =$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $model=new ChamaDefaulter;
                $model->attributes=$defaulter;
                if(!$model->save()){
                    throw new Exception("Error saving details", 1);

                }
            }elseif($TotalContributed<0){
                // he has balance expected              
                $oustandingBalance+=$contributionAmount;
                $defaulter['amount_defaulted']=$contributionAmount;
                $defaulter['date_defaulted']  =$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $model=new ChamaDefaulter;
                $model->attributes=$defaulter;
                if(!$model->save()){
                    throw new Exception("Error saving details", 1);

                }
            }else{
                //Contribution received as expected;               
                $amountContributed+=$contributionAmount;
                $contributionDetails["amount"]=$contributionAmount;
                $contributionDetails["date_paid"]=$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');                
                $model=new ChamaContribution;
                $model->attributes=$contributionDetails;
               if(!$model->save()){
                    throw new Exception("Error saving details", 1);

                }

            }
            $TotalContributed-=$contributionAmount;
            $start->modify('+1 day');
        }

        exit("User oustanding Balance is KSH $oustandingBalance");
    }
```

Comment: What did **you** try? Where **exactly** are you struggling with it?

Comment: You could run a daily job that subtracts the daily amount from a user's balance table and adds it to a payment table. A user's balance can go negative, and be made positive by later payments. Since payments are subject to disagreement, _always_ add data rows, don't update them - if you lose history then you won't be able to resolve financial disputes.

Comment: (Voting to close, but the above should give you something to go on. Can we see a database schema from you first? That would be a good start).

Comment: Thanks for the edit - most people who are prompted for code never come back! Can you now outline what the problem is with this code? (Feel free to reply in the comments, but this information could do with being added to the question also, so new readers do not need to wade through comments to discover the actual question).

Comment: @halfer i have added a code segment of what i had initially, the contributionDetails array holds details of each contribution per user and insert it as a row for future reference the defaulter array hold another row of defaulter details e.g the amout defaulted etc

Comment: @halfer thanks for your assistance, the main issue here is to add auto detect logic to detetect when user have overpaid and if overpaid, the algorithm to distribute the amount evenly as described above if he had underpaid, the algorithm should add a row in the defaulter row, the last paid date should be picked as recently added row in the contributions tables

Comment: You don't need to consider over/underpaid - whilst someone is a member of your site, just subtract the daily membership fee from their account every day.

Comment: @halfer please clarify this statement **'A user's balance can go negative, and be made positive by later payments. Since payments are subject to disagreement, always add data rows, don't update them - if you lose history then you won't be able to resolve financial disputes'**

Answer (score 0):

You've asked me to clarify my comment, thus:

> A user's balance can go negative, and be made positive by later payments.

Sure. You will need a payments table, and since you charge on a daily basis, you need to make an entry every day. You could equally have a weekly charge, and then charge every week - it's up to you.

Let us assume you maintain just a payments record, and calculate a balance dynamically when required. Your entries might look like this:

```
User     Value    Purpose    Date
1        600      Payment    2015-04-03
1        -200     Daily      2015-04-03
1        -200     Daily      2015-04-04
1        -200     Daily      2015-04-05
1        -200     Daily      2015-04-06
```

You can see here that this user became a member on the 3rd April, and has been charged 200 somethings every day. Their balance can be worked out as -200 (assuming the above is all the records for this user); whether you permit them to take part in member activities during that state is entirely up to you. You might, for example, allow users to default for a certain number of days, or only by a certain amount.

When this user makes a new payment, that gets added in the usual way, which may or may not take them back into credit.

> Since payments are subject to disagreement, always add data rows, don't update them - if you lose history then you won't be able to resolve financial disputes

Storing a user's balance is not as important as storing their individual payments - you can calculate their balance from their payments minus their charges, but you cannot calculate their payments from their balance.

Let us assume you don't take my advice, and just use a balance table:

```
User     Balance    Last updated
1        -200       2015-04-06
```

Now the user claims they made a payment yesterday, which may or may not be true. You could ask them to produce proof (e.g. a payment gateway receipt) but it is much easier if you can find this information in your own system.

Comment: Thank you@halfer, for this let me implement this logic i will surely give you feedback on this. Regards